# my permission command doesn't work properly

Tags: permissions, find

```
find . a* -exec chmod o+r {} \;
find . *d -exec chmod o+x {} \;
```

I want to give `o+r` to all files that start with "a" and `o+x` to all files that end with "d", but these lines seem to affect all files under the directory.

Answer (score 3):

Put a* and d* under quotes, so that shell would not expand them,and also add -name keyword. If you only want to search for files and not also directories for example then add -type f.

```
find . -name 'a*' -type f -exec chmod o+r {} \;
find . -name '*d' -type f -exec chmod o+x {} \;
```

If you want to change only in current directory and not subdirectories, add -maxdepth option

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name 'a*' -type f -exec chmod o+r {} \;
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*d' -type f -exec chmod o+x {} \;
```